# How to add comments to inline CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want to comment out some css style that is inline (inside some html tags). How do I do this? Do I use the /* */comments from CSS? Or `<!-- -->` for html?

```
<span class="color_dark" style="top:20px;font-size: 17px;line-height: 0px;position: relative;">onbezorgd genieten van uw<br> haard of kachel</span>
```

This is the part I am talking about. I wantto comment out some style properties.

Comment: Try both and see which works!

Comment: use `/* */` for comments inside style attributes

Comment: Try searching SO next time, or google. Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14410811/why-does-comment-out-a-style-rule-but-does-not

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `/*` and `*/`.

```
<span class="color_dark" style="top:20px; /*font-size: 17px;*/ line-height: 0px;position: relative;">onbezorgd genieten van uw<br> haard of kachel</span>
```

You can see that Google Chrome uses those too when disabling a style on a page.

*And google your question next time first please.*

Comment: *And [duckduckgo](https://duckduckgo.com/) your question next time first please.*

Comment: Thanks! I'll accept your answer in 3 minutes.